# Ruby Console multiline

Tags: ruby, console

This is basically a very noob question about Ruby console (IRB), but I couldn't find answer anywhere. So. When writing a statement in Ruby console and then in the middle of it pressing Enter, sometimes console expects me to continue the statement and start to look like this:

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :093">

That " basically tells (i think) that Ruby expects me to finish the statement on the previous line. However there is no way I can finish it or cancel the statement. Pressing Enter again doesn't really help, and also Ruby stops computing other statements if I enter some at this point.

So, what is this mode and how to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your quotes are unbalanced; enter a quote.

```
irb(main):004:0> s="this is
irb(main):005:0" a test"
=> "this is\na test"
```

You can also hit `Ctrl-C` `<Return>`, which will drop you to the root prompt. `Ctrl-D` will drop you back to the prompt, but the next `<Return>` will throw an error due to the unterminated quote.

Alternatively, use [pry](http://pry.github.com/), which will let you use `!` to escape back to your top level.

Answer (score 0):

You can still finish the previous statement. Ruby is telling you that you opened a double-quoted string on the previous line, and didn't close it. Just enter a `"`; the result may be a syntax error, but at least your console will become usable again.

Answer (score 0):

The quotation mark `"` indicates that you're in the middle of a string. You can either close the string or, if you press `Ctrl-C` it should kill the current statement.